# animated view similar to popover view in Ipad

Tags: ipad, popup

I have a table view and it is populated by some data. I want to add something in the didSelectedRow function , such that a view opens up taking up most of the screen and the previous view darkens but is behind this newly popped over view ( similar to the animated view opening when clicking any image in the music folder of Ipad). I would just like to know what is that particular functionality called so that I can implement it.

Previously I was using popoverview controller which enabled me to display a popover but I dont like using it and I am looking for alternatives.

I am just unable to find the exact name of what I want to implement. 
It would be great if anyone could just tell me the name of the property/function I can use to implement what I need.

The functionality I want is something similar to presentModalViewController. However, I dont want to use presentModalViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about `presentModalViewController:animated:` with a `modalPresentationStyle` of `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

If that is not what you mean, you would have to construct it yourself with a semi-transparent container view (dark background color) that covers the whole screen containing a smaller content view.

Comment: exactly.. I want something similar to that.. is there something else I can use other than presentModalViewController?

Comment: As I said, if the modal view controller does not meet your needs, build and animate it yourself. It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: @ Ole Begemann I ended up using presentModalViewController... I am having a split screen view in which my detail view is a scroll view having 4 table views in it... so for trial, I added "presentModalViewController" in the didSelectRow of one table views... What happens here is that when I click on a cell is that, the view does come up but it comes behind my split screen view, because I can see a part of the view on the sides of my split screen view.. would you know how I can solve this problem?